# I have a Dart problem when I use map in a stream

Tags: dictionary, dart, stream

I create a simple stream, add a few elements and listen to the stream. But there is a problem when I use the map on the stream. For simplicity I just map the value to the same value (I guess?).

When I try to run the program I get an map-error:

```
Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of '_MapStream<String, dynamic>': type '_MapStream<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<String>'
```

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {

  StreamController controller = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  final StreamTransformer transformer = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (data, EventSink sink) {
        sink.add(data);
    }
  );
 
  Stream stream = controller.stream;

  stream
    .map((value) => value) // <-- Problem in this line
    .transform(transformer)
    .listen(
      (data) {
        print('listen: $data');
      },
      onError: (err) => print(err));
  
  controller.add('foo');
  controller.add('baa');

  controller.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are forcing non-generic types from generic types. If you write the code like this where you are not use explicit typing:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  final controller = StreamController<String>.broadcast(); // <-- fixed here

  final StreamTransformer transformer =
      StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
          handleData: (data, EventSink sink) {
    sink.add(data);
  });

  final stream = controller.stream;  // <-- fixed here

  stream
      .map((value) => value) // <-- Problem in this line
      .transform(transformer)
      .listen((data) {
    print('listen: $data');
  }, onError: (err) => print(err));

  controller.add('foo');
  controller.add('baa');

  controller.close();
}
```

Dart will then automatically determine that the type is `StreamController<String>` and `Stream<String>` and not `StreamController` and `Stream` which you are enforcing.

When you are removing the generic part of the type you are also removing Dart's ability to guess the type for all methods you are calling.

If using explicit typing you should write:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  StreamController<String> controller = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  final StreamTransformer transformer =
      StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
          handleData: (data, EventSink sink) {
    sink.add(data);
  });

  Stream<String> stream = controller.stream;

  stream
      .map((value) => value) // <-- Problem in this line
      .transform(transformer)
      .listen((data) {
    print('listen: $data');
  }, onError: (err) => print(err));

  controller.add('foo');
  controller.add('baa');

  controller.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a comment. Why does the error only occur in the map line:

.map((value) => value) // <-- Problem in this line

Comment: The error comes from your `.transform(transformer)`. Your `transformer` is made as the type `StreamTransformer<String, String>` which means it takes a `String` and convert it into a `String`. But because `map` cannot determine the return type of `value` it most assume that `value` are `dynamic`. So `map` returns a `Stream<dynamic>` which are not compatible with your transformer.

Comment: I should add that you can tell `map` what type it is going to return on runtime by writing `.map<String>((value) => value)`. This will also fix you code but in general you should not throw away the generic part of types.